# redirect to base url on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have a web application using Struts 2 that when an action returns an error, will redirect to `index.action?notSupported=true`.  Is there a way from here to on page reload go to `index.action` rather than `index.action?notSupported=true` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```
window.location.href=window.location.href.substr(window.location.href,window.location.href.indexOf('?'))
```

Hope this helps...